# Delegate conformity and MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I can't understand why I must declare conformity to both `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` when using `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Failure to simply declare conformity to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` results in a compiler warning about assigning to '`id<UINavigationControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type ViewController *const __strong'`

Why isn't declaring conformity to `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and implementing the delegate methods in my header enough?

There aren't even any `UINavigationControllerDelegate` delegate methods to implement...

Relevant code...

Mmmmplementation:

```
-(void)shareTrainInformation
{
    NSLog(@"Sharing...");

    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    messageComposer.delegate = self;

}
```

Header:

```
@interface RRDetailViewDrillDownViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: How are you assigning the composer's delegate?

Comment: do you have a navigation controller anywhere?

Comment: Yup my app has a navigationController.

Comment: Updated the question with code...

Comment: Just use the composer's mailComposeDelegate property: `composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;`

Comment: Hmmmm.... that fixes it - why is the delegate property for MFMessageViewController called MessageComposeDelegate? and how is it different from 'delegate' as I used above? - for example a tableView's delegate property is just called delegate...

Comment: @0x7fffffff is right. When using the message and mail composers, they have specific delegate property names.

Comment: It's because that name was already taken by an unrelated delegate declared in the superclass. (UINavigationController declares a `delegate` property.)

Comment: Ahhh of course, so I was effectively setting the inherited (but unrequired) superclass delegate! which is why it wanted me to declare  UINavigationController conformity... add as an answer and i'll accept. cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the composer's mailComposeDelegate property: `composer.messageComposeDelegate = self;`

It's because that name was already taken by an unrelated delegate declared in the superclass. (UINavigationController declares a delegate property.)